# I need to make it so the sentence and numbers that are outputted are stored into a file

Tags: python

The code I have made:

- asks the user for a sentence,
- makes it lower case so it is not case sensitive
- splits the sentence into separate words so each word can have a number assigned to it according to its position

> How can I add a part to my code that saves the sentence inputted by
>   the user as a file, along with the numbers that get assigned to each
>   word?

Here is my code:

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence")
sentence = sentence.lower()    
sentence = sentence.split()    
positions = [sentence.index (x) +1 for x in sentence]
print(sentence)    
print(positions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `raw_input` if you want to treat everything as strings. You do not need to store the positions but, instead, get them from the wonderful `enumerate` function. Then write to the file like so

```
sentence = raw_input("Please enter a sentence: ")
sentence = sentence.lower()    
sentence = sentence.split()    

open('filename.txt','w').writelines(["%d-%s\n"%(i+1,x) for (i,x) in enumerate(sentence)])
```

Comment: does this work:     file = open('sentence.txt', 'w')

                            file_numbers = open('positions.txt', 'w')

Comment: If you want to open 2 files, you can do that as well. Just make sure you close both of them when you're done :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence")
sentence = sentence.lower()    
sentence = sentence.split()  
wordPositionDict = {}  
( wordPositionDict.get(x,[]).append(i+1) for i,x in enumerate(sentence))

print wordPositionDict[word]
```

append all the index for each word to dict. after iterate all the words in sentence you will have one dict which key is the words and value is the list of index

Comment: This is way above my skill level, is there no way to do it in a more simple way?